# PingIdentity: Configure SAML Connection: Your changes cannot be saved

Tags: authentication, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

I'm whole new to authentication using SAML

Trying to register my app with Ping Identity (Identity provider).

While adding new application I followed steps as

1. New application
2. WEB APP
3. Choose connection type → SAML selected
4. Configure
5. Create app profile
6. Configure SAML Connection → Provided all necessary information

When click on **Save and Continue** it shows message pop up as **Your changes cannot be saved.

I have provided information as
ACS URLs -> http://localhost:8080/saml/sso, ENTITY ID -> pingOneapp, ASSERTION VALIDITY DURATION (IN SECONDS) -> 60

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a preceding space in your ACS URL. Can you try removing the space before http://localhost:8080/saml/sso and try to enter the ACS URL again? You should then be able to save it,
-Gregg

Comment: Issue was from Ping Identity side.
It got resolved after sometime.
And started facing similar issues on other pages.